# Visual Studio 2015 (C++) : Stop compile on first build error (not first project)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

How to stop the compilation of Visual Studio 2015 when it detects compile error?

I mean **first build error** (may be first `.cpp`), not **first project** because it takes too much time.
 (I have only 1 project.)

An extension named ["**StopOnFirstBuildError**"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EinarEgilsson.StopOnFirstBuildError) is not an answer,
because it stop on **first project** that has error.

### Question

(more elaborate)

When I pressed <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+B</kbd>, the compiler would compile all (or some) files.
In my case, it can detect some errors using only 5 seconds, so I want it to stop compiling NOW.
However, the VS 2015 become non-responsive.
It also has strong resistance against <kbd>Ctrl+Break</kbd>.
It takes about 30 seconds before I can navigate to the location of error.
How can I stop the compile-process on the first compile error automatically?

### History

There is [an old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134796/automatically-stop-visual-c-2008-build-at-first-compile-error) asked about this for Visual Studio 2008.
Its most accepted solution is to go to :-

```
Visual Studio -> Tools -> Macros -> Macro IDE...  (or ALT+F11)
```

and paste [a certain piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085245/3577745).

However, [macro is not supported anymore in VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013-2015).
(I tried to press <kbd>Alt+F11</kbd> in VS 2015, no macro editor / menu appear.)

The claim is consistent with [a question for VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3041982/3577745) stated that the above trick is not work.

[The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042159/3577745) for the VS2010 question is to install an extension named ["**CancelFailedBuild**"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NoahRichards.CancelFailedBuild).

Thus, I downloaded it.
When executed `.vsix` (the installer), it said
"This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.".
... it makes sense because the extension said "Works with : Visual Studio 2010, 2012".

**Now I think I am left with a single choice :-**
Use macro (the old VS 2008 way) by installing [**Macros extension**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/05/11/macros-extension-open-sourced-in-visual-studio-2015/).
(The extension is a result of [users' complain about losing the old macro feature](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2650757-bring-back-macros).)

Is downloading the extension a good idea?
If so, what is the step after that?    Is there a code that I should copy-paste?
If not, what is the easier way?

Sorry for posting a lot of hyperlinks.

### Workaround

Below are the approaches that may alleviate some inconvenience, but do not answer the actual question at all.

1. [Install a patch that make Visual Studio responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37752155/3577745), so <kbd>Ctrl+Break</kbd> works.
   It requires me to press keyboard manually.
   It seems to work only for Windows 7.  (not tested)
2. Shorten compile time by creating a simple dummy `.cpp`, then [compiling only that single file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2332199/3577745).
   It is useful for some cases.

Comment: *it makes sense because the extension said that "Works with : Visual Studio 2010, 2012* You can usually unzip the `vsix` and change the manifest.

Comment: @ta.speot.is How?  I have zero knowledge about `vsix`.   I guess it might also call some script functions that exists only in older versions of VS.

Comment: It's just a zip file. https://grantwinney.com/how-to-get-old-extensions-to-work-in-newer-versions-of-visual-studio-specifically-how-to-use-the-visual-studio-2013-color-theme-editor-in-vs-14/

Comment: @ta.speot.is  It works for this plugin ("CancelFailedBuild").  Just modify the manifest to `<VisualStudio Version="14.0">`  Very easy.  Thank! If you want, you can post it as a solution.  :)

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The solution for the VS2010 question is to install an extension named "CancelFailedBuild".
>
> ...
>
> *This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.*
>
> ...it makes sense because the extension said that "Works with: Visual Studio 2010, 2012."

Visual Studio 2012 extensions are frequently compatible with VS2013 and VS2015. You can update the extension yourself by unzipping the `.vsix` file (it's just a ZIP archive) and updating its manifest (which is an XML file).

[This guide](https://grantwinney.com/how-to-get-old-extensions-to-work-in-newer-versions-of-visual-studio-specifically-how-to-use-the-visual-studio-2013-color-theme-editor-in-vs-14/) shows you the XML elements to change.